# devexpress layout control vertical alignment

Tags: layout, devexpress, controls

I have searched the net, but found not the required info.

I have a devexpress layout control on my form. Then I added a chart control to it.

Now, on the left there is a layoutcontrolitem1 and on the right is the chartcontrol.

With which property can I arrange the layout control items vertically?

There is the property DefalutLayoutType of the layout group. This is set to vertical, but no effect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, on the left there is a layoutcontrolitem1 and on the right is the
>   chartcontrol.

I believe you are talking about the [LayoutControlItem's Label](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2176).
Item labels can be displayed at any edge of an item. The item label's position within the item is specified by the [BaseLayoutItem.TextLocation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraLayoutBaseLayoutItem_TextLocationtopic) property. You can set this property to `Locations.Top` either manually in code-behind or via [designer](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2199).

Please also review the help-articles about the LayoutControl's [Customization Capabilities](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2166).